# Can I use axes.lines.remove(line) of matplot axes method from other thread?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, python-multithreading

I am using matplotlib to plot graph as below.

for adding plot lines to figure I am using main GUI thread(with pyplot.plot method) and to worker/other thread to update plot axis data as there is more number of plots. update function is run by thread, I used to remove some unwanted plot lines. does removing plot lines from worker/other thread allowed?

As shown in code I am remove line as below :
if len(self.plot_lines) > 5: # remove last line untill total line = 5
    self.axes_plot.lines.remove(self.plot_lines.pop())

## please go through below code

```
import os
import sys
import random
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle('Update Plot with Qthread.....')
        self.threadpool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
        self.threadpool.setMaxThreadCount(2)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()        # to update plot on some time interval
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timerEventOccued)
        # Add figure object using figurecanvas
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas  = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)
        vbox.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.canvas.draw()
        # draw plot using main thread
        self.draw_plot()


    def timerEventOccued(self):
        worker = Worker(self.updatePlot)
        self.threadpool.start(worker)  # Execute using Qthread

    def draw_plot(self):
        rect = [0.07, 0.065, 1, 1]
        self.axes_plot = self.figure.add_axes(rect, xlabel='Xaxis (deg)', ylabel='Yaxis (deg)')
        self.figure.gca().xaxis.labelpad = 0
        self.figure.gca().yaxis.labelpad = 0
        self.figure.gca().tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=7)
        self.figure.gca().tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=12)
        self.axes_plot.margins(.20, .20)
        self.plot_lines = [ self.axes_plot.plot([],[],marker='o')[0] for i in range(0,10)]  # Create 10 plot lines 
        self.timerEventOccued()
        if not self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.start(1500)

    def updatePlot(self):
        """This function will be run by worker thread"""
        for index,line in enumerate(self.plot_lines):
            data = index * (random.random())
            line.set_data([0,data],[0,data])

        if len(self.plot_lines) > 5: # remove last line untill total line = 5
            self.axes_plot.lines.remove(self.plot_lines.pop())    

        self.axes_plot.relim()
        self.axes_plot.autoscale_view()
        self.canvas.draw()



class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    """
    Worker thread

    Inherits from QRunnable to handler worker thread setup, signals and wrap-up.
    """

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        """
        Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
        """

        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        try:
            self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except Exception as E:
            print "Exception while worker Thread Run", str(E)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Can I remove annotation and arrow object or any plot line from worker/other thread?**

The above code is simple example how to add plot line and update it but In my complex code with same architecture I used to got below exception which cause core dump.

I got below logs after core dump occurred and this scenario is not consistence.

**Exception RuntimeError: RuntimeError('main thread is not in main loop',) in > ignored
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread**

Please let me know if I am missing some step to use matplotlib with threading.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's part of complex code. I have just put summary of how I have used matplotlib to create plot with threading.Specific to multi-threading, I am using PyQt threadpool:

Comment: SO recommend in these cases that you provide an MCVE, that is to say that you create a minimum and complete code that allows us to verify the problem, analyzing it and providing possible solutions, so you want to help yourself and provide what you have been asked for.

Comment: I have edited question with some example code. can you please provide input

Comment: @eyllanesc can you please guide me if you have any idea for above issue?